# How to understand declaring dependency with `configuration` in gradle?

Tags: maven, configuration, gradle, dependencies

In a gradle file, I need to add the dependency of `com.google.guava:guava:16.0`, I can write:

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0'
```

without `configuration`.

Or use configuration `default` or `compile` or `runtime` or `test`:

```
compile configuration: 'default', group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0'
compile configuration: 'compile', group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0'
compile configuration: 'runtime', group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0' 
compile configuration: 'test', group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.0'
```

There is no error when I run `gradle compileJava`.

But if I try other values, like `testCompile` or `any-other-value`, it will report:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Module version :gradle-test:unspecified, configuration 'compile'
  declares a dependency on configuration 'testCompile' which is
  not declared in the module descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:16.0
```

Where can I find the `module descriptor` file and the configurations it declares?

I found the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0/guava-16.0.pom, is it the `module descriptor`? But I can't find anything about `default/compile/...` configurations.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? If you want to add guava to the compile classpath, just use `compile com.google.guava:guava:16.0`. If you only want it for tests, just use `testCompile com.google.guava:guava:16.0`

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not support multiple configurations (ivy does) and yes the pom file is the module descriptor in your case. Just using the notation without configuration should be fine. Also, I couldn't reproduce the failing testCompileJava task you reported

Comment: Yes, for a ivy module descriptor, I can see the configurations declared in the `ivy-???.xml` clearly, so I know which one I can use. But for a maven, since there is no explicit declarations, how can I know which one I can use (although it's correct which specifying any configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Gradle defined some configurations for dependencies come from maven repo:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/ivyservice/ivyresolve/parser/GradlePomModuleDescriptorBuilder.java

We can use them in gradle dependency configuration.